# Implementing a HashDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, collections

I'm trying to implement a `HashDictionary` in C#. However, I'm having some problems. I won't post all my code, but inside the `HashDictionary` class I got an `HashDictionaryEnumerator : IEnumerator`. The constructor for it looks like this:

```
public HashDictionaryEnumerator(LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>[] buckets
{
    this.buckets = buckets;
    FirstNode = buckets[0].First;
    CurrentNode = FirstNode;
}
```

I also have a method that's supposed to go through the has hash table, one node at a time together with a method that goes to the next bucket. Since that `HashDictionary` class isn't ready, I can't really try it with that (I suppose?). But I used it in another more simple program and it seems to work...?

```
// Return true if there is another bucket (even if it's null)
// else return false
public bool NextBucket()
{
    Index++;
    if (Index < 100)
    {
        for (; buckets[Index] == null && Index < 100; Index++) { }
        CurrentBucket = buckets[Index];
        CurrentNode = CurrentBucket.First;
    }
    return Index < 100;
}
                                                                   
public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (CurrentNode == null || CurrentNode.Next == null)
    {
        return NextBucket();
    }
    CurrentNode = CurrentNode.Next;
    return CurrentNode != null;
}
```

Anyway, the class above is, as said, inside the `HashDictionary` class. There I'm supposed to implement

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() { }
```

I have another `GetEnumerator()` method that looks like this.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new HashDictionaryEnumerator(Buckets);
}
```

I guess it works, but since the other `GetEnumerator()` isn't implemented I can't try that one either. Don't really know how to implement the other enumerator.

I also have a `bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)`. It's supposed to find if a key exists. I can't, however, compare a key the item like `tmp.Value == item`.

Don't really know what to ask, but don't know how to get this thing sorted out. Maybe a hint in the right direction? Also, here's my `Add()` method inside `HashDictionary`. I'm not sure if that's workable way to add a key:

```
// Add a key to the hash dictionary
public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair = new(key, value);
    Buckets[GetIndex(key)] = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
    Buckets[GetIndex(key)].AddLast(pair);
}
```

Don't know what I'm supposed to write here, but I've done all the above.

Comment: Wouldn't the `HashDictionaryEnumerator` implement `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`? The two `GetEnumerator` methods could then have the same implementation as `IEnumerator<T>` is derived from `IEnumerator` - see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1).

Comment: You're right. Somehow I managed to figure out there rest and I think I've maybe completed it. Thanks! :)